# What is the best way of letting Future values, into case class constructer, that doesn't accept futures?

Tags: scala

Constructing a case class, that its constructer values coming by Future.
as example:

```
case class Info(values: Seq[Int], result: Long)
val vs: Future[Seq[Int]] = getValues()
val r: Future[Long] = calcValues(vs)
```

I want then to construct the ***Info*** by something like this:

```
    val info = Info(vs,r)
```

what is the best way of succeeding the ***vs*** and ***r*** futures for the constructure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use for comprehension, like below.

```
val future: Future[Info] = for (
  vs <- getValues();
  r <- calcValues(vs)
) yield Info(vs, r)
```

This returns a Future[Info] which you can map over and do your other operations.

Comment: Well thanks, but is that is the better. As example: Info(await(vs), await(r));

Comment: You are blocking on the future which is not recommended. You should try to avoid blocking at all times.

Comment: Yes, that is the way